# How to install CppStyle in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, google-style-guide

I would like to use the [CppStyle](http://www.cppstyle.com/) Plugin in Eclipse within my projects, but I have some problems during the installation:

I tried to install it using the Eclipse [Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cppstyle#undefined), but I get the fallowing error:

```
The following solutions are not available: CppStyle 1.2.5.0 (id=org.wangzw.cppstyle.feature.feature.group, site=http://www.cppstyle.com/)
```

If I use the direct link within the "Install new Software" wizard, there are no software items listed.

I tried this with with a fresh downloaded version of Eclipse CDT Neon, Luna and Kepler. I am using Ubuntu 16.10.

Does any body know how to install CppStyle properly?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked perfectly with [Neon.1a 64-bit](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/1a/eclipse-cpp-neon-1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 16.04 from the marketplace. If the issue is 16.10 perhaps there is a 16.10 bug in Eclipse that needs to be addressed.

Comment: PS CppStyle is at version 1.3 on the marketplace and 1.4 on http://www.cppstyle.com/mars/ (there does not seem to be a neon specific update site). Where did you get the 1.2.5 version from?

Comment: Hello Jonah, thank's for testing on your machine. I'm now going to try it with Ubuntu 16.04 within a virtual machine. 

I think there was an update for CppStyle within the last 20 hours. I just tried it again and now: I have the same error message, except the version. It is 1.3.0, too.

Comment: It works for me as well with Neon.2. The version of CppStyle I get from the marketplace is 1.4.0.6. My OS is Debian 8.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tested it now with Ubuntu 16.04 and I had the same issue. So the Problem is not the OS. I figured now out, that the problem is within my ugly proxy server. :-( I'm so sorry for wasting your time.